# Hadoop Mapreduce detailed task status queries

Tags: hadoop, visualization

I want to write a 3rd party frontend to hadoop mapreduce which needs to query mapreduce on some information and statistics.

Right now I'm able to use `hadoop job` to query jobs and the map and reduce completion percentages, along with counters, e.g.:

```
# hadoop job -status job_201212170023_0127

Job: job_201212170023_0127
map() completion: 0.6342382
reduce() completion: 0.0

Counters: 28
    Job Counters 
        SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=4537
...
```

What I would also like are the numbers of each task, as used by the visualisation within the job tracker, i.e.:

[image: job tracker chart]

I am able to list all the mappers...

```
# hadoop job -list-attempt-ids job_201212170023_0127 map running
attempt_201212170023_0127_m_000000_0
attempt_201212170023_0127_m_000001_0
attempt_201212170023_0127_m_000002_0
...
```

..but how would I get the percentage of each of these tasks? Ideally I would want something like this:

```
# hadoop job -task-status attempt_201212170023_0127_m_000000_0
completion: 0.6342382
start: 2012-12-18T12:23:34Z
... etc.
```

The current solution would be to scrape the web interface, but I'm not a fan of this if it is at all possible to use the command line output.

Comment: Have you seen [ambrose](https://github.com/twitter/ambrose), by the way?

Comment: @om-nom-nom I have not. It looks good. Will have to give it a go.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the JobClient API?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I'm not using Java.

Comment: Well technically you are, `hadoop job` is running the java class `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient` and dumping the output to stdout, so if you can't find a solution using that cmd line wrapper that works for you, then consider looking into the source for this class and amending to suit your needs

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. Technically I am running a Java process when I call `hadoop`. Thank you for the correction.